# Get complete filepath string from asp:FileUpload object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a form linked to a ticketing system. The user can select what file they want to attach through the asp:fileUpload object. I was wondering how I can extract the full file path from the asp:FileUpload object; something like "C:\Documents And Settings\My Documents\info.txt" as an example.

I'm coding in visual basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be able to do that, web applications shouldn't know the structure or content of the end user's file system for security purposes. I can't think of a reason why your web application would even need to know something like that.

As long as you have the file, and you know where you need to store it server side (db/filesystem/etc), I'm not sure what the requirement could be.

Comment: A user may need to create a ticket with an attached file. I want the user to get a dialog box that allows them to navigate to the file that they want as opposed to manually entering the file path. Then I when I put an attachment to a ticket, I am required to know the file path in order to put a file attachment to the ticket.

Comment: the asp:fileupload control has a button that allows the user to browse their hard drive and look for the file. The control then passes the file to your server side code. All you need to know is where to store the file once they've passed the bits for that file to the server side code. If you're storing it on the file system, you can simply put it in a directory in  your app using Server.MapPath("/myfiles/"); or something similar

Comment: http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/ here's a basic tutorial on how it works

Comment: Thank you. Can vb code delete a file in the directory as well once its been used?

Comment: on the server it can, if you want to delete a file you'd use the System.IO name space and do something like this File.Delete(Server.MapPath("/myfiles/myfile.doc"));